# Adding a primary key in SQL Server 2005 not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am pretty new to database stuff in general and I can't seem to get any sample code for creating a primary key to work. I am using Microsoft SQL Server and the server type is SQL Server 2005 (90). The code I am currently trying to use is:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerVisit
ALTER COLUMN CustomerID int NOT NULL;
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerVisit PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID)
GO
```

But I am getting an error:

> Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'

I just created this table and it has no constraints or anything. Just 3 columns. I've also tried

```
ADD PRIMARY KEY CustomerID;
```

but that results in

> Incorrect Syntax new the keyword 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add constraint` comes after `alter table`. The `;` ends the previous `alter table`, so you have to start the new statement with `alter table` again:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerVisit ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerVisit 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID);
```